# What is the meaning of these Windows Environment variables: HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH, HOMESHARE, USERPROFILE

Tags: windows, samba

What is the meaning of these Windows Environment variables:

- HOMEDRIVE,
- HOMEPATH,
- HOMESHARE,
- and USERPROFILE?

Who set them? When?
Who use them? For doing what?

How the configuration of the samba server modify these variables?

Answer (score 41):

`USERPROFILE` is set by `userenv!LoadUserProfileW` which is called when, well, loading the user's profile (the `HKEY_USERS\<sid>` hive).

- This typically happens the first time a process is started for the user.
- If you specifically arranged not to load the profile (e.g. with `/noprofile` for `runas`) then the process is run in the `Default User` profile which still has this variable set - since the moment *it* was loaded at system's startup.

`HOMEDRIVE`, `HOMEPATH` and `HOMESHARE` (as well as several other variables) are set by `shell32!RegenerateUserEnvironment` which is called on Explorer initialization<sup>1</sup>. They are placed in the (volatile) `HKCU\Volatile Environment` key which, being volatile, persists until the profile's unload.

- Consequently, they are only set when the user logs into their desktop session. NOT for secondary logons or services.

  - No wonder people prefer `USERPROFILE` nowadays.
- [For `HOMEPATH` to be set, `SYSTEM` must have permissions for the profile's directory](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/homepath-variable-has-disappeared/d1d12afd-4b06-4c6f-ba16-bd189fef198f) (they are initially set, of course, but may vanish when e.g. playing with Cygwin's `chmod`).

<sup>1</sup><sub>The code also sets a few variables that are already set by `userenv`. This suggests that this is older code that persists since NT4 days. [Difference between profile and home path - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/29948/difference-between-profile-and-home-path) confirms that.</sub>

Comment: very interesting that HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH don't exist if the user has never logged in (read: ran explorer.exe)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, they helps me to understand a problem that happend for me in git-bash for windows (See this https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/2709)

Answer (score 24):

`HOMEDRIVE`/`HOMEPATH` is where the user's personal files are: downloads, music, documents, etc.

`HOMESHARE` is used instead of `HOMEDRIVE` if the home directory uses UNC paths.

`USERPROFILE` is used to store the user's application and OS configuration files and personalization settings. It includes both local and roaming (Active Directory) folders. It seems like people favor using this more than `HOMEPATH` nowadays.

It's important to note that although `HOMEDRIVE`/`HOMEPATH` is often the same path as `USERPROFILE`, it's not always the case.

I don't think Samba would modify these. It might make use of them to provide an initial (home) directory. Active Directory may change them though.

---

References:

- [dead link] <s>[Environment Variables in Windows NT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100843)</s>
- [Where Should I Store my Data and Configuration Files if I Target Multiple OS Versions?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/)

Comment: Quote: "It's important to note that although HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH is often the same path as USERPROFILE, it's not always the case." Do you happen to know when it is different?

Comment: I believe the HOMEDRIVE/HOMEPATH directory can be modified fairly easily - e.g. to use a network share or different hard drive - in which case it would become different from USERPROFILE.

Comment: @CarlBosch E.g. [`net user <username> /HOMEDIR:<path>`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320043) can set it (there since at least win2k).

Comment: Note that %HOMEPATH% should always be preprended with %HOMEDRIVE%

Comment: %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH% can be set by the organization via Active Directory ([source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e9d9cd4d-6882-459e-b7a8-7091cfa031d2/where-are-user-environment-variables-homedrive-homepath-set?forum=winserverTS)). In my case they were set to a network drive location.

Answer (score 3):

if you go to the run box and type any of the above like this

%HOMEPATH%

then it will go to your environment path that is set on your machine.  It's usefull when writing vb scrips and things like that where you want to perform a task on the users profile area for example.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't really work depending on the config and current drive of the Explorer process... On my machine, %HOMEPATH% is `\ ` (%HOMEDRIVE% is `Z:`) and if I put %HOMEPATH% in the Run window, it opens `C:\ `... (now, I can't guarantee it would always open that specific drive)

Answer (score 1):

Those are all set on login, and they are, as SocialAddict said, very useful in scripts when you need to perform an action on different systems.

I'm not too clear on your other question, a samba server shouldn't care about those variables.

See http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm for a detailed explanation.