# Where is the global git config data stored?

Tags: git, config

When using `git config --global` to set things up, to which file will it write?

Example:

```
git config --global core.editor "blah"
```

I can't find it at these places:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig

C:\myapp\.git\config
```

I have not set an ENV?

My Git version: 1.6.5.1.1367.gcd48 –
on Windows 7

Comment: Are you using msysgit or something else?

Comment: `git config --global --edit` should tell you the exact location no matter what kind of setup you have--just look at what file comes up in your editor.

Comment: `git config --global --list` was also useful for when it doesn't exist as it gave the location of where git is expecting it to be.

Comment: For me, that command yields: e -w: e: command not found

Comment: @AJP: This is exactly my problem, but how to change where it wants to save/read it from??

Comment: In the case of TortoiseGit, it seems to get it from the Environment variables... See https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1925

Comment: Related: [Where is git config coming from?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17756753/456814).

Comment: On Aptana Studio 3 it is found at the following location: %AptanaStudio3Workspace%\.metadata\.plugins\com.aptana.portablegit.win32\etc\gitconfig

Comment: Just to add to @MatrixFrog's comment, once opening `git config --global --edit` you'll probably end up in vim.  From vim to get the full file path you can enter `:echo expand(':%p')` -- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file

Comment: Adding to the comment by @user420667, the command is actually `:echo expand('%p')`, i.e. without the colon inside the call to `expand`

Comment: git config --list --show-origin will tell you the location

Comment: git doesn't automatically create the file. The file doesn't exist until git writes to it for the first time. So where is it? The fact is, it might not actually exist.

Comment: As a note, on linux `strace -fefile` in front of a command will show you every path it touches by name. so `strace -fefile git config --global -l`.

Answer (score 1664, accepted):

Update 2016: with git 2.8 (March 2016), you can simply use:

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

And with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), you can [add a `--show-scope` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286340/6309)

```
git config --list --show-origin --show-scope
```

You will see which config is set where.
See "[Where do the settings in my Git configuration come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670933/6309)"

As [Stevoisiak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3357935/stevoisiak) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to/2115116#comment79861204_2115116),

> it will work with non-standard install locations. (i.e. [Git Portable](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

(like the latest [`PortableGit-2.14.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.14.2-64-bit.7z.exe), which can be uncompressed anywhere you want)

---

Original answer (2010)

From [the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> #### --global
>
> For writing options: write to global `~/.gitconfig` file rather than the repository `.git/config`.

Since you're using [Git for Windows](http://msysgit.github.io/), it may not be clear what location this corresponds to. But if you look at etc/profile (in `C:\Program Files\Git`), you'll see:

```
HOME="$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH"
```

Meaning:

```
C:\Users\MyLogin
```

(on Windows 7)

That means the file is in **`C:\Users\MyLogin\.gitconfig`** for Git in Windows 7.

Comment: I was being really dumb, I didnt add the "--global" flag to the edit command! "git config --global --edit" showed the file with all my config changes, "git config --edit" was the file I kept opening and thinking, where is that editor/compare/etc config item I just set! Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I've seen other places were it said it's at %USERPROFILE%.  On my computer HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH are remapped to a network drive.  Searches on my local drive were coming up with nothing.  So this helped a lot.

Comment: Really useful, I was having the same issue - if you're on a domain with a mapped home drive it will try and create the git config there. This would make a good feature request - use %HOMEDRIVE% or %USERPROFILE%

Comment: Why is this called global, when it is only for one user? Wouldn't (for unix) `/etc/gitconfig` be "global" and `~/.gitconfig` only be "local"..... and I guess `.git/config` "hyper-local" ----- Basically, I find the "global" term for this confusing, and I was wondering if there was a good reason for the nomenclature?

Comment: @PeterAjtai "global" because it is for all your repository. As opposed to "local" (only for one repo) or "system" (which is for all repo, for all users)

Comment: Modifying $HOME seems to only affect MSysGit when using its "Git Bash" shell. Even though the moved .gitconfig is visible in the shell, my PhpStorm client will prompt for user.name and user.email, then write them to my Users\username\ directory.

Comment: @N13 I don't use PhpStorm, but I use msysgit in `cmd` only, not in bash. And setting `HOME` does influence a `git cmd` session as well.

Comment: If your using Cygwin shell's, and Git for Windows, git looks for .gitconfig in ~/ , which is not the same if you use a batch shell. And honestly, I avoid batch shells like a plague

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606483/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-windows-enviroment-variables-homedrive-homepath/36392591#36392591 about how `HOME*` variables work in Windows and how to handle problems with them.

Comment: I do not see these files in my machine, but I beleive I am looking in the wrong places. I've been using git for windows and TortoiseGit, mostly operating from git bash, without issues for a long time.

Comment: @Raj simply type `git config --list --show-origin`: that will list the actual files used by `git config` on your machine.

Comment: Turns out that the user-specific files like those in a .git repository were on a different drive altogether than my git install due to IT configurations where I am.

Comment: I add some underlying info. Say my git is in "C:\Git\cmd\git.exe". It is in Path-variable. Using sysinternals process monitor I found that it is indeed the correct git but it is not the one that does the config writing. No writing happend with that image. Inital git spawns the actual git which is C:\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe  Now it searches for user settings in two folders: c:\users\username\.config and  c:\users\username\.config\git\config

Answer (score 145):

I was also looking for the global `.gitconfig` on my Windows machine and found this neat trick using git.

Do a: `git config --global -e` and then, if you are lucky, you will get a text editor loaded with your global `.gitconfig` file. Simply lookup the folder from there (or try a save as...), et voilà! :-)

Comment: Running this command will also create a `C:\Users\<user_name>\.gitconfig` if it is missing.

Comment: I'm running in a non-windowed mode and cannot find the location anywhere

Answer (score 103):

On *nixes, it's in `~/.gitconfig`. Is there a corresponding file in your home?

On Windows, you can type this in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway):

```
notepad ~/.gitconfig
```

Comment: This should be the same on windows.

Comment: If you wanna get to it easily, write an alias :) Here's mine: `alias gitconfig='open -a Sublime\ Text.app ~/.gitconfig'`. Use whatever text-editor you want.

Answer (score 45):

The paths for msysgit are:

**Windows Vista+** `C:\Users\<user_name>\.gitconfig`

Comment: Probably better to describe this as %USERPROFILE% then the answer will work for all Windows versions, past, present, and future.

Comment: Except I think it's actually %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% as in other answers, which is equal to %USERPROFILE% in many cases, but some of us have IT configurations pointing it to a mapped drive instead.

Comment: @ojchase is correct.  I'm in a corporate environment, where %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% is mapped to a network drive.  This means the gitconfig cannot be found when I'm off site, which then breaks anything that relies on the gitconfig.

Answer (score 35):

The global location is derived, on Windows MsysGit, using the HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH environment variables, unless you have defined a HOME environment variable. The is detailed in the 'profile' script.

In my corporate environment the HOMEDRIVE is H:, which is then mapped to a network URL \\share\$. The whole lot is then mapped to be "My Documents", which isn't where others would expect. There may have been some further problems with the drive to URL remapping. I don't even get to adjust the HOMEDRIVE or HOMEPATH variables anyway.

In my case I have defined a personal HOME environment variable and pointed it to D:\git\GitHOME and copied all those GIT files (which are without and extension) to the GitHOME directory for safe keeping.

The windows environment variables can be set via the Advanced tab in the My Computer properties dialog.

Comment: I was scrolling through the answers about to post on the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` variables, since they just caught me out while using Bower. It seems a number of utilities on Windows read from `<system>:\User\<username>\.gitconfig, while the Git tool itself saves to `%HOMEPATH%\.gitconfig`. I had to go one step further and copy the updated config file from my `H:` (our network uses the same drive letter for that) to my local user folder, only then did Git use the rules correctly when called by Bower.

Comment: @ZaLiTHkA, In my corporate network the user's Home (H:) drive is them re-mapped back to the C:\User\ location as well, so I'd not noticed that. If you can identify which are the FOSS utilities that make the mistake then that would be useful info for helping getting round to reporting/fixing those tools. If they are internal corporate tools you are on your own ;-)

Comment: Unless it's more complicated than a simple setter line, I'm not seeing HOME defined in the etc\profile script.  It does still seem to act as described, but I'm unclear where HOME is being set nowadays.

Comment: @ojchase My part of the answer of where --glob config is written related specifically to Windows. The core Linux git writes to places such as where the XDG thingy directs (i.e. I'm aware that linux writes to other places and has other conventions, and importantly it does have a root directory while Windows has 'Drives' ;-)

Comment: @PhilipOakley I was actually referring to Windows too; sorry I was unclear.  Combining your answer and others, I was expecting some sort of `HOME = $HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH` (or similar) line in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile` and that line doesn't seem to exist, but probably used to?  I haven't been able to figure out exactly what is setting $HOME unless it's set by environment variable which I'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 21):

**When is the global .gitconfig file created?**

First off, git doesn't automatically create the global config file (.gitconfig) during its installation. The file is not created until it is written to for the first time. *If you have never set a system variable, it will not be on your file system.* I'm guessing that might be the source of the problem.

One way to ask Git to create it is to request an edit. Doing so will force the file's creation.

git config --global --edit

If you monitor the user's home folder when you issue this command, you will see the .gitconfig file magically appear.

**Where is git configuration stored?**

Here's a quick rundown of the the name and location of the configuration files associated with the three Git scopes, namely *system*, *global* and *local*:

- System Git configuration: File named **gitconfig** located in **-git-install-location-/ming<32>/etc**
- Global Git configuraiton: File named **.gitconfig** located in the user's home folder **(C:\Users\git user)**
- Local Git configuration: File named **config** in the **.git folder** of the local repo

Of course, seeing is believing, so here's an image showing each file and each location. I pulled the image from an article I wrote on the topic.

[Windows Git configuration file locations (TheServerSide.com)](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved)

[image: Location of Git configuration files]

Comment: there is a forth place called the portable config : [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2634/git-integration-global-settings-from-command-line.html) they mention the 4 places ; 
 **Git for Windows supports four levels of configuration. At the lowest level is the machine specific configuration settings known as "portable" and lives a "%ProgramData%\Git\config"**

Answer (score 15):

As @MatrixFrog pointed out in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to#comment8398511_2114111), if the goal is to edit the config, you might want to run:

```
git config --global --edit
```

This command will open the config file (in this case, the `--global` one) in the editor of choice, and await for the file to be closed (just like during `git rebase -i`).

Comment: You can use this to figure out where the global `.gitconfig` is located - as long as your editor tells you what directory the file is located in. You can also use other switches (`--system`, `--local`, etc.) to find and edit other `.gitconfig` locations.  P.S. `-e` is the same as `--edit`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using TortoiseGit on a windows PC you can use:

```
Settings / Git / Config / Edit global .gitconfig
```

to open the global .gitignore file.

But if you use your Windows (7) PC in a domain your profile dir is may be a network share (mounted as a drive). In this case TortoiseGit (at least:1.6.5.0) is pointing you to the wrong dir (on c:...). See the closed TortoiseGit [issue 922](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/922) for more information. Or using %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% to open the dir that contains the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 10):

I am using [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) with msysgit on Windows 8.1 and noticed that there can be three different locations for the `gitconfig` file:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig
C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGitHg\git\etc\gitconfig
```

But the one that is used is the one from `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 9):

Just completely agree with @[cameron-mckenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106996/cameron-mckenzie)'s answer [here on this page, above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50901991/7076660) about **When is the global `.gitconfig` file created?** (this clearly applies in case of every OS). Rest of his answer deals with Win7 systems.

In **Win10 systems** too, the `.gitconfig` global file would create for the very first time only when you tend to set `user.name` & `user.email` system variables via windows command-prompt.
As soon as it's set, the `.gitconfig` file would get created  in `%USERPROFILE%` dir.

###### Below command works for Win & MacOS, both

So, let's suppose if `.gitconfig` file already exists. You can know its location via Command-prompt/Gitbash/Terminal by :

```
git config --global --list --show-origin
```

Answer (score 6):

It might be useful to note (for *nix platforms): some types of global git configuration/information are stored in `/usr/share/git-core/`, such as git autocompletion scripts and the following (default) hooks:

- applypatch-msg
- post-update
- pre-commit
- prepare-commit-msg
- commit-msg
- pre-applypatch
- pre-rebase
- update

Each of these can contain their own set of commands to execute, at the time described by their respective filenames.

Answer (score 4):

I am running Windows 7 and using git as setup by following the instructions on GitHub (a year or two back). A rather common use-case I would have thought. None of the answers above helped me, and after much frustration I eventually found my 'real' gitconfig file in the following directory;

C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_054f2e797ebafd44a30203088cd
3d58663c627ef\etc

Obviously substitute your user name and presumably the suffix after PortableGit_ is a unique GUID or similar.

Comment: This is only the case when using GitHub for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I had also a problem with my global `.gitconfig`
This is for the case someone also has this strange

git said:

> fatal: unknown error occured while reading the configuration files

Now I fixed it. The problem was a second `.gitconfig` in this folder:

> c:\Users\myUser.config\git\config

I don't know where it came from... But now everything works like a charme again.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is important to post this quote:

> Git for Windows supports four levels of configuration. At the lowest level is the machine specific configuration settings known as "portable" and lives a "%ProgramData%\Git\config". One priority level us the installation specific configuration settings known as "system", which live at "\mingw64\etc\gitconfig". Both of these configuration file, generally require elevated privileges to modify.
>
> Starting with the use specific values known as "global" configuration, which can be found at "%UserProfile%.gitconfig", we find the "user editable" configuration files. The highest priority configuration settings are in the "local" configuration, which can usually be found at ".git\config".
>
> It see the recommendation in the blog linked is to modify the "system" or "installation" specific configuration settings, which is fine but users should expect that other installations of Git would not absorb said settings. If you want machine wide settings, use the "portable" configuration file, otherwise choose the "global" or "local" configuration files.
>
> Hopefully, people find this information useful.

[source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15847/git-config-unknown-config-fileugitconfig.html)

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall Msysgit and install Cygwin + Git. Then global '.gitconfig' will be here: C:\cygwin(64)\home\[userName]\.gitconfig .

Now you don't have to worry about an environment variable which may be used by other programs. For example, my environment variable pointed me to a mapped drive in my work windows domain environment. I dont want my global .gitconfig sitting on my "home" mapped drive. I also don't know what might happen to other applications that might rely on that windows environment variable. Operations division might need that environment variable set to the mapped drive for a reason.

Also you don't have to worry about Mysysgit overwriting your 'profile' configuration settings if you specify a specific path to global '.gitconfig', using this method.

In general, save yourself and use cygwin bash shell in windows and be happier

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue; the problem was that the `.gitconfig` file was located in

```
C:\Users\MyLogin\.gitconfig\
```

(on Windows 7)

In other words, the file was located in **`C:\Users\MyLogin\.gitconfig\.gitconfig`**, instead of on **`C:\Users\MyLogin\.gitconfig`** (which is where Git was looking for the files).

Answer (score 2):

## `.gitconfig` file location

> macOS testing OK

### global

```sh
# global config
$ cd ~/.gitconfig

# view global config
$ git config --global -l
```

### local

```sh
# local config
$ cd .git/config

# view local config
$ git config -l
```

---

> maybe a bonus for you：`Vim` or `VSCode` for edit git config

```sh
# open config with Vim

# global config
$ vim ~/.gitconfig

# local config
$ vim .git/config


# open config with VSCode

# global config
$ code ~/.gitconfig

# local config
$ code .git/config
```

Answer (score 1):

Per https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config you can see the `--global` references the `~/.gitconfig` file:

> --global For writing options: write to global **~/.gitconfig** file rather than the repository .git/config, write to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
> file if this file exists and the ~/.gitconfig file doesn’t.
>
> For reading options: read only from global ~/.gitconfig and from
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config rather than from all available files.
>
> See also FILES.

The FILES reference https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES does show reference to the `~/.gitconfig` being the global configuration file:

> FILES By default, git config will read configuration options from
> multiple files:
>
> $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig System-wide configuration file.
>
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
>
> **~/.gitconfig**
>
> User-specific configuration
> files. When the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable is not set or
> empty, $HOME/.config/ is used as $XDG_CONFIG_HOME.
>
> These are also called "global" configuration files. If both files
> exist, both files are read in the order given above.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed my Git in: `C:\Users\_myuserfolder_\AppData\Local\Programs\Git`

Answer (score -1):

`git help config`

Files section have a detailed description.

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72645293/edit) (it covers answers and most kind of text as well). Thanks in advance.