# Window Git $ git config --global http.proxy warning: http.proxy has multiple values

Tags: git

Why do I see the following warning?

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://172.19.18.22:8080
warning: http.proxy has multiple values
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simple display all three configuration level (system, [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to/2115116#2115116) and local) in order to check if you see several `http.proxy` configuration:

```
git config -l
```

You can then proceed to remove the extra one with a:

```
git config --system (or --global or --local) --unset http.proxy
```

[liwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140938/liwp) mentions in the comment a:

```
git config --system (or --global or --local) --unset-all http.proxy
```

to get of all `http.proxy` entries

Comment: I had to use --unset-all instead of --unset to get rid of both entries. Otherwise git would just complain again that there are multiple entries.

Comment: Note that you can also use `--replace-all` for setting an existing config value without adding another entry