# How to configure GIT on Windows 7 to push project to Google Code

Tags: git, windows-7, google-code, .netrc

I would like to push my project to Google Code.

I created a new project, in tab Source I have got few instructions how to push my local code.

I work on Windows 7, so I created a directory

```
C:\googlecode
```

and I put there file

```
_netrc
```

and inside

```
machine code.google.com login myloginhere@gmail.com password MySecretCodeHere
```

After that I added new System Variable(sorry, I use non-english version of Windows)

```
HOME
```

[image: System Variables]

I clicked OK, OK.

Following the instructions, I cloned this repo:

```
git clone https://path/to/repo
```

I added a new file README

```
touch README
git add *
git commit -m "README"
git push origin master
```

and here I got an error:

```
fatal: remote error: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see https://code.goo
gle.com/hosting/settings
```

What more I should do to make it works?

---

I restarted my computer and I run command `SET HOME`

[image: HOME]

I copied `git-credential-netrc` file to driectory;

```
C:\Users\Aleksander\Documents\googlemagic
```

Checked:

[image]

Then, I went to diectory with my repo and I run a command

```
git config credential.helper netrc -d -v
```

It printed an output:

```
usage: git config [options]

Config file location
    --global              use global config file
    --system              use system config file
    --local               use repository config file
    -f, --file <file>     use given config file
    --blob <blob-id>      read config from given blob object

Action
    --get                 get value: name [value-regex]
    --get-all             get all values: key [value-regex]
    --get-regexp          get values for regexp: name-regex [value-regex]
    --replace-all         replace all matching variables: name value [value_rege
x]
    --add                 add a new variable: name value
    --unset               remove a variable: name [value-regex]
    --unset-all           remove all matches: name [value-regex]
    --rename-section      rename section: old-name new-name
    --remove-section      remove a section: name
    -l, --list            list all
    -e, --edit            open an editor
    --get-color <slot>    find the color configured: [default]
    --get-colorbool <slot>
                          find the color setting: [stdout-is-tty]

Type
    --bool                value is "true" or "false"
    --int                 value is decimal number
    --bool-or-int         value is --bool or --int
    --path                value is a path (file or directory name)

Other
    -z, --null            terminate values with NUL byte
    --includes            respect include directives on lookup
```

I was trying to modify this command line but without any result. I tried to add

```
'$shortname -f netrc'
```

or change options `-d -v` but then, I have no output.

---

Command: `git config credential.helper "netrc -d -v"` worked. Output below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to make sure `HOME` is actually defined in your session.
To be sure, close your `cmd` shell, reopen it and type set HOME to see it does reference the right folder.

Second, you need to check that the [credential helper netrc](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc) is activated:

- copy the [git-credential-netrc](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/credential/netrc/git-credential-netrc) file anywhere in your %PATH%
- add:

  ```
  cd yourRepo
  git config credential.helper "netrc -d -v"
  ```

(the `-d` and `-v` will show you what is actually used when looking for your password)

Finally, your remote upstream repo should include your login in it:

```
git clone https://myLogin@example.com/myRepo
```

Try to avoid a login with a '@' in it (like an email), or [you would need to encode that '@' sign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19511469/6309) (`%40`).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried to follow your instructions but I cannot finalize step with *git config...*. I edited my post and I wrote, what exactly I have done.

Comment: @IWillTryToCodeIt try with quotes (I have edited my answer). Why is there so much spaces when you display your `%PATH%`?

Comment: a quick answer to your question: I just wanted to make it more visible...edited.

Comment: This command worked, I edited my question and I posted an output.

Comment: @IWillTryToCodeIt for the error message, you can follow http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529889/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/16706254/6309.