# Why is Git not prompting me for password?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to set up a Git/Bitbucket account so I can source control one of my projects. I created a Bitbucket account and created myself a repository as well.

I am on Step 1 part 8 of [Clone Your Git Repo and Add Source Files](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Clone+Your+Git+Repo+and+Add+Source+Files) in the Atlassian documentation.

I keep getting this error:

```
 fatal: could not read Password for 'https://newuserme@bitbucket.org': No such file or directory
```

So I ran the command

```
git config --global core.askpass
```

And then tried again, however, it is still not prompting me to enter the password. What am I missing here? (Note: I am using the Clone link from my actual repository and not the one shown here. :))

Comment: What os are you using

Answer (score 3):

Instead of git config --global core.askpass, you can try:

```
git config --global core.askpass /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

(as commented in [GitExtensions issue 85](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/85#issuecomment-970122))

Note that you can also use a credential helper to cache your password: see for instance "[How to configure GIT on Windows 7 to push project to Google Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498465/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

On windows this worked for me:

`git config --global credential.helper wincred`