# What is the difference between push.default "matching" and "simple"

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote, git-config

I have been using Git for a while now, but I have never had to set up a new remote repo myself, and I have been curious to do so. I have been reading tutorials and I am confused on how to get `git push` to work.

If I simply use `git push`, it asks me to see up a "default branch" to point to. What is the difference between these two options it supplies me with?

```bash
git config --global push.default matching
git config --global push.default simple
```

The `matching` option just pushes whatever branches I have on my local repo, and if they don't match I have to then manually tell it to push whatever new local branches I have, correct? Is this best practice to use or is `simple` best?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in Git 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148066/warning-push-default-is-unset-its-implicit-value-is-changing-in-git-2-0)

Comment: Now, if only `pull.default` is available for updating all those branches locally

Answer (score 418, accepted):

`git push` can push all branches or a single one dependent on this configuration:

**Push all branches**

```
git config --global push.default matching
```

It will push all the branches to the remote branch and would merge them.
If you don't want to push all branches, you can push the current branch if you fully specify its name, but this is much is not different from `default`.

**Push only the current branch if its named upstream is identical**

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

So, it's better, in my opinion, to use this option and push your code branch by branch. It's better to push branches manually and individually.

Comment: I liked the `push.default current` from @UpAndAdam answer. Does not knew about it.

Comment: Note that `simple` is no longer an option. In `1.7.8.4` (and earlier?) it results in an error when you try to push. but `current` is still available

Comment: @sixty4bit: I am using git version 1.7.1.  I am using `tracking` -> push the current branch to its upstream branch.

Comment: @sixty4bit No, it got included in a later Version of Git i don't know in which but (1.7) is old as hell though, even for 2016. I wouldn't recommend using such old Versions at all.

Comment: Downvoted. Sorry, but the linked page's description of `simple` doesn't make sense, contradicts this answer, and is incorrect - which makes this answer confusing. The linked page says `simple` "will push branches one by one. Mostly connected with current branch." Does that mean it will push the branches sequentially as opposed to in parallel? What does "mostly connected" mean? Then, the description for `simple` goes on to quote the description for `matching`, which one would think means the description for `matching` also applies to `simple`. But obviously that is not true.

Comment: When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

Comment: @sixty4bit as of git 2.21 `current` is still available. `tracking` is a deprecated synonym for `upstream`  Simple is like upstream with added safety that it only works if the names are the same.  This is really handy if you are 'forking' off an upstream branch and want to constantly keep synchronized with it by merges and rebases.

Comment: With this I still need to specify a branch for `pull`, even after `push` :(

Answer (score 104):

From GIT documentation: [Git Docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Below gives the full information. In short, `simple` will only push the `current working branch` and even then only if it also has the same name on the remote. This is a very good setting for beginners and will become the default in `GIT 2.0`

Whereas `matching` will push *all* branches locally that have the same name on the remote. (Without regard to your current working branch ).  This means potentially many different branches will be pushed, including those that you might not even want to share.

In my personal usage, I generally use a different option: `current` which pushes the current working branch, (because I always branch for any changes).  But for a beginner I'd suggest `simple`

> #### `push.default`
>
> Defines the action `git push` should take if no refspec is explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push destination), `upstream` is probably what you want. Possible values are:
>
> - `nothing` - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.
> - `current` - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
> - `upstream` - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called `@{upstream}`). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
> - `simple` - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch's name is different from the local one.
>
>   When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you
>   normally pull from, work as `current`. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.
>
>   This mode will become the default in Git 2.0.
> - `matching` - push all branches having the same name on both ends. This makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push **maint** and **master** there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have these two branches, and your local **maint** and **master** will be pushed there).
>
>   To use this mode effectively, you have to make sure all the branches you would push out are ready to be pushed out before running `git push`, as the whole point of this mode is to allow you to push all of the branches in one go. If you usually finish work on only one branch and push out the result, while other branches are unfinished, this mode is not for you. Also this mode is not suitable for pushing into a shared central repository, as other people may add new branches there, or update the tip of existing branches outside your control.
>
>   This is currently the default, but Git 2.0 will change the default to
>   `simple`.

Comment: yes, but I assume even with the push.default setting that if you do "$ git push *origin master*", it will only push the current branch to origin to the branch on origin with the same name...right? you should mention that there is also a default remote

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at.  In ANY MODE if you say `git push origin master` it will do the same thing.  The point of the modes and defaults is generally what happens when you simply say `git push` and you don't tell it a remote or a branch.  What default setting? you mean the default setting of push.default? the default setting in which version of git... if you dont get it your comment is extremely vague.

Comment: 'push.default
Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given'  if you say git push origin master you are giving it more information and it still might not do what you describe; depending on the refspec you set up.. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec

Comment: you may want to also see the difference between `simple` and `current` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918418/5506988

Answer (score 7):

As [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21866819/241211) shows, `push.default` has [many options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault) now. If you find yourself looking back and forth between the descriptions to see the differences, try using this chart:

| Behavior | `simple`<sup>1</sup> | `upstream`<sup>2</sup> | `current` | `matching` | `nothing`<sup>3</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Push checked-out branch | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |  |
| Push other branches |  |  |  | ✔ |  |
| Upstream branch must be configured | ✔ | ✔ |  |  |  |
| Upstream branch name must match | ✔ |  | ✔ | ✔ |  |

<sub><sup>1</sup> `simple` is the default setting value since Git v2.0, released in 2014.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> `upstream` has a deprecated alias, `tracking`.</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> `nothing` requires all options to be specified on the CLI.</sub>

---

I have various repositories each set to `simple`, `upstream`, and `current`. I find `matching` to be a little too wild for me, but I can imagine circumstances where it's useful.

Comment: love the graph!

Answer (score 3):

## Git v2.0 Release Notes

### Backward compatibility notes

When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
traditional "matching" semantics so far (all your branches were sent
to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the "simple" semantics,
which pushes:

- only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
  when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
  branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
- only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
  are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.

You can use the configuration variable "push.default" to change
this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
"matching" semantics, you can set the variable to "matching", for
example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

When `git add -u` and `git add -A` are run inside a subdirectory
without specifying which paths to add on the command line, they
operate on the entire tree for consistency with `git commit -a` and
other commands (these commands used to operate only on the current
subdirectory).  Say `git add -u .` or `git add -A .` if you want to
limit the operation to the current directory.

`git add <path>` is the same as `git add -A <path>` now, so that
`git add dir/` will notice paths you removed from the directory and
record the removal.  In older versions of Git, `git add <path>` used
to ignore removals.  You can say `git add --ignore-removal <path>` to
add only added or modified paths in `<path>`, if you really want to.