# Am I going to push to the same commits?

Tags: git

I was going to push my commits, but some error appeared and I'm lucky, bc as it shows I was going to push to the same commits (I think). I'm afraid that I'll broke something by pushing to double commits.

Why? Look at this:

```
[john@pc]$ git push
// useless stuff
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 2.63 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 18 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0)

// here it goes
remote: Audit failure - Commit 3876b44 - Non-full name: johngitacc
remote: Audit failure - Commit 3876b44 - Non-full name: johngitacc
remote: Audit failure - Commit 6757f52 - Non-full name: johngitacc
remote: Audit failure - Commit 6757f52 - Non-full name: johngitacc
```

Why there 2x2 same commits: two of **3876b44** and two of **6757f52**?
Can it be caused by the reason these commits was created in different **local** branches and then they were **cherry-picked** from that branches? AFAIK, no, bc I deleted these branches after cherry-picking, but "double-titles" still there. What can be the reason? Am I going to push the same commits?

P.S. I shortened the **SHA-1**s of commits for readability.

**UPD.:**

I ran `git config user.name "John Pushandpop"` command. Then `git push` and got the same output, but a little bit changed those 4 lines:

```
remote: Audit failure - Commit 3876b44 - Non-full name: John
remote: Audit failure - Commit 3876b44 - Non-full name: johngitacc
remote: Audit failure - Commit 6757f52 - Non-full name: John
remote: Audit failure - Commit 6757f52 - Non-full name: johngitacc
```

Comment: what `git status` shows?

Comment: Sounds like your server is expecting certain items of meta-data to come in a certain format with the commit or it won't allow you to push. The solution may be something like `git config user.name 'John Pushandpop'`. It seems to think that the formatting of your name is important

Comment: @OstapMaliuvanchuk, ```Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.```

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I know that and I'll fix it, but before I wanna know whether I'm going to push 2 double commits.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "double commit". Things with the same SHA1 are identical as far as git is concerned. The message you are seeing is output by the server-side auditing script, which is just printing a message multiple times for whatever reason (probably because you fail on multiple criteria for the same commit).

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ok, I got it. So, should I just set "full name" and try to push again? I'm concerned bc I can break repo for others since I have write access.

Comment: You can try push them to a new remote brunch and see what happens, if it's ok then push to master and delete the branch.

Comment: Yes, do what Ostap Bender says

Comment: @OstapMaliuvanchuk, well, setting ```user.name``` doesn't help. I've updated my question.

Comment: Set the name globally with `git config --global user.name "Your name"`

Comment: @OstapMaliuvanchuk, Yes, you're right. This is what it needs from me ;) Can you post it as answer, so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your global user name with :
`git config --global user.name "Your name"`

If you want to test what happens in case you push your commits to master you can just push them to new remote branch. But as @MadPhysicist said it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a duplicated commit - if it has the same hash, it's the same commit.

As they told you in the comments, it *may* be that the remote script is processing each commit twice because of an error or poor programming - who cares? As long as it detects the issue, it's not *that* relevant if it's informed twice.

But the other alternative that wasn't mentioned is you may be pushing **two** branches instead of one. Try doing `git push origin master` instead of just `git push` to see if this is the case.

If it is, you may want to [change the `push.default` config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21866819/641451) to something like `current` so `git push` only pushes the current branch to it's remote counterpart.