# How to git push to remote tracking branch with different base name?

Tags: git

Pushing from local branch "master2" to remote "origin2" creates a new remote branch "origin2/master2". How can I have it push automatically to "origin2/master"?

I have two remote tracking branches known as

```
origin/master
origin2/master
```

I have two local branches:

```
master
master2
```

Created as follows:

```
git checkout -b master origin/master
git checkout -b master2 origin2/master
```

Git tells me that it has automatically set up the local branches to track the remote branches; example:

```
Branch master2 set up to track remote branch master from origin2.
```

I've had no problem with local branch master pulling and pushing to origin/master by simply using "git pull" and "git push" while on that branch.  However, when I'm on master2, "git push" creates a remote branch:

```
origin2/master2
```

My config has the following entries generated automatically:

```
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.master2.remote=origin2
branch.master2.merge=refs/heads/master
```

I'm aware that I could do this, but I'm wondering if there's a config setting to get around it:

```
git push origin2 master2:master
```

Output of git --version:

```
git version 1.8.2.1
```

Note: I've obfuscated some names here, so hopefully I didn't make any mistakes in the transpose.  Please address them in the comments if you see any and I'll fix them.

Comment: check push.default, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839651/git-what-is-the-difference-between-push-default-matching-and-simple

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21866819/1256452) from question that Andrew C linked.  Specifically you probably want to use the `upstream` setting.  Note that you can set this per repository instead of globally (it's your choice how to fuss with `push.default`, you can even set this globally *and* per-repository).

Comment: The question wasn't terribly helpful, but you're right. The answer was to set push.default=upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set:

```
push.default=upstream
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run `git push --set-upstream origin2 master2:master` if you're pushing the branch for the first time. The branch will be set to track `origin2/master`.

You can also set the upstream branch of an existing branch:
`git checkout master2; git branch -u origin2/master`. This also sets the tracking branch to `origin2/master`, any subsequent `git push` will push to `origin2/master`.

See [git's documentation about tracking branches](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html#Tracking-Branches) for details.

Comment: The refspec style name:name stuff applies only for fetch and push, not for upstream settings.  But you're right that the general method here is to fuss with the push refspec.

Comment: I posted my config settings and mentioned that the upstream was already set, but thanks.