# git - how to push and pull currently checked out branch

Tags: git

Is there anyway to set the setting of `git pull` and `git push` to only pull and push the currently checked out branches, rather than all tracking branches.

I know you can do it by specifying the branch, but is there anyway to do it without having to specify the branch ?

Comment: `git checkout -b <branch>` can chackout the branch and if you wish to push it back then you can use `git push -u origin <branch>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - What is the difference between push.default "matching" and "simple"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839651/git-what-is-the-difference-between-push-default-matching-and-simple)

Comment: "pull", in Git, means "fetch, then merge or rebase". The fetch that pull runs defaults to a limited fetch that fetches only the current or named branch(s), and the merge or rebase step necessarily affects only the current branch.