# Git push to single branch

Tags: git, branch

I have a repo and I'd like to push to the `develop` branch.

I have used

```
$ git checkout develop
Already on 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
```

And also done `git pull` of the `develop` branch.

I expect

```
$ git push
```

To push to the develop branch. But that isn't what's happening.

```
djave at djave-comp in ~/projects/project on develop*
$ git push
Counting objects: 49, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (49/49), 25.45 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 49 (delta 38), reused 0 (delta 0)
To bitbucket.org:djave/project.git
   f311657..16b42c7  develop -> develop
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'djave@bitbucket.org:djave/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

It looks like it is pushing to `develop`:

```
   f311657..16b42c7  develop -> develop
```

But then is also trying to push to the `master` branch (and fails):

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

I expect it to just push to the `develop` branch and be successful.

How can I make git push just push to the `develop` branch?

<sup>Sorry if this is a duplicate (have searched extensively but can't find the right combination of issues) or the title doesn't use the correct terminology (feel free to update the title)</sup>

Comment: @SurajRao ah yes – thank you

Answer (score 0):

Dont use git push alone, the command can have parameter :

```
git push <remote_alias> <branch_name>
```

So in your case you can use :

```
git push origin develop
```

Comment: This may be a silly question. Is there a way to say "When I am on a branch and use git push, only push to this branch"?

Comment: Ah maybe `git push origin HEAD`

Comment: @Djave you can use a config for this, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839651/git-what-is-the-difference-between-push-default-matching-and-simple