# gitconfig: locations of git configuration files

Tags: git, system, global, git-config

How can I find/list the *global* and the *users config* files? I mean "Git-native functionality", not Linux commandos like `find`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to) a comment indicated how to know which file is related to `--system`, `--global` and `--local`.

In short you just use `--edit` to `git config`:

```
git config --system --edit
git config --global --edit
git config --local --edit
```

If you replace the environment-variable `EDITOR` with e.g. `echo` you can receive it in a variable, ie. you can use it programmatically:

```
t=`EDITOR=echo git config --system --edit`
echo $t
```

prints `/etc/gitconfig` in my case.