# How can I keep example config files in GIT?

Tags: git

I have a config file for our debug output system that contains a bunch of example lines. I want all of the engineers to get the basic version of this file when they clone the repo.

I don't want to commit my changes to this file. I want to ignore my changes, but leave the file in the repo for everybody else.

How do I do this? If I git ignore the file then git wants me to commit my changes to .gitignore to the repo. Changing my ~/.gitignore seems to have no effect - the changes still show up in SourceTree.

BTW, I did search around and find this thread. But it doesn't seem to do what I am looking for.  [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` ???

Comment: Consider using a global config that they can modify locally.  Here's a so post that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to

Answer (score 0):

If you update your index ([`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index)) in order to instruct git that this file "hasn't changed", then your local modifications won't have to be committed:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged -- yourFile
```

This is a local solution though: anyone else can still modify and commit changes for that same file.