# Change Git user in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ IDEA was used by another user and when I try to push to Git, I was asked a password of this user.

How can I change user in my IDEA? I tried to change global Git user, but it is not working.

Answer (score 151):

1. Go to the base directory of your project.
2. You will find a hidden directory called `.git`. Enter into it.
3. There you will see a file called `config`. Add the following code.

   ```
   [user]
         name = username
         email = username@domain.example
   ```

Comment: In the base directory of my project, I don't find this file. Adding it did not help.

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki If the directory '.git' is not found, then this code not cloned from github. Please make sure that you are cloning your project from github repo.

Comment: Ah ok- I was probably looking under a git submodule, instead of the parent.

Comment: you can do it more simple,,, 
1. Go to the base directory of your project.
2. 
`git config user.name "yourusername"`
`git config user.email "youremail@email.com"`

Comment: I think that Bitbucket users do not have the name and email fields in the .config file, instead we need to change the url field.

Comment: In case you're dealing with multiple Github accounts and some weird IntelliJ behavior, where it's absolutely unclear where IJ gets the wrong account user data from, this is the answer to go for.

Comment: @vishvAsvAsuki It's there only hidden in IntelliJ, if you open in explorer or folder you will see the .get directory.

Answer (score 43):

You can change it global via any of the 2 options.

1. "Git Bash" which comes with the git installation package.
2. In IntelliJ View > Tool Windows > Terminal (Alt + F12).

Use command :

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to change it in IntelliJ, not globally.

Comment: Similarly there is user.email parameter, which could be changed as well.

Answer (score 21):

```
Go to VCS -> Git -> Remotes
```

There you can edited your `git remotes` by changing user in the URL https://user@serc-bitbucket.

In your next Push you'll be prompted to a dialog to enter your password, and in the next your credientials.

Comment: How would you format the url if the username you have is an email address?  Im trying to set the username for using google's repos and they use your email address as a user name.  Ive tried https://user@domain.com@source.developers.google.com/..... but that failed.

Answer (score 19):

I found a solution myself: just find hidden .git file in your project root, open it, and change user.

Comment: Should be .git/config file

Answer (score 12):

I had faced similar challenge with changing my user, when I was pushing files directly from IntelliJ Idea and though the files were updated in GitHub it was being updated from a different account.

Turns out there's a file called .gitconfig in windows where the user name and email is stored.

```
C:\Users\<USER_DIR>\.gitconfig 

[user]
    name = <USERNAME>
    email = <EMAIL>
```

Changing the email here changed my account.

Here the [blog](https://alvinalexander.com/git/git-show-change-username-email-address/) & a [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-is-the-global-git-config-data-stored) I used for reference.

Answer (score 8):

Go to below link.

```
File-->Settings--->Version Control -->GitHub
```

If you need to connect to Bitbucket, you need to change the host to bitbucket.org

Comment: Not Github, Git. I have bitbucket repo

Comment: then you should have bit bucket setting under Setting tab,

Comment: I do not have settings for bitbucket in Idea, just need to find where to change user

Answer (score 1):

Just change in terminal in IntelliJ Idea an URL of your project. Put yours instead of `${urlToYourProject}`.

```
git remote set-url origin ${urlToYourProject}
```

Then update project (Ctrl+T). And you'll see the dialog where you can set your credentials.

Don't forget that you can use other remote name instead of `origin`!

Answer (score 1):

Update the user or the repo URL (depends what you really want to change) in you project by entering the .git folder (in your project) and modifying the "config" file respectively.

When using azure devops I needed to change the repo url which contained the token I had to change ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite like the previous answers, since one user was used for all projects, and it is not necessary to change it everywhere when changing the password.

```
C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\vcs-users\
```

Deleting the contents of this folder worked for me. I'm not entirely sure that this folder is responsible for storing information about git users, but judging by the name, this is it.
Before deleting, just in case, make a backup of the folder.

P.S

```
C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\options\vcs.xml
```

It looks like just logins for different projects are stored here. But no password.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows machine and git is using the Windows credential manager, then you can change the username and password in the credentials manager:

[image: windows credentials example]

To check if git is using the windows credential manager:

```
$ git config credential.helper
!"C:/dev/git-2.32/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-credential-wincred.exe"
```

And to check if IntelliJ git is using the credential manager:
[image: intellij git settings]

Answer (score -3):

Go to File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub and enter your Login and Password there.

Comment: Not Github, Git. I have bitbucket repo