# How do I set user.email and user.name in Intellij 14 with GIT integration?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, intellij-14

I have IntelliJ 14 with GIT integrated. `git push` command shows the Author as `unknown`. How do I set the following two parameters in my IntelliJ IDE?

```
git config --global user.name "Sam Smith"
git config --global user.email sam@example.com
```

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `git config user.name`?

Answer (score 28):

You can set the username and email for **Intellij 14** with **GIT** integration as follows. This worked for me.

Go to your project where git is **initialized**.

Then enable the hidden folders and find "`.git`" and go inside the folder.

Find the file called "`config`" and add below code and save.

```
[user]
      name = username
      email = username@domaim.com
```

Answer (score 23):

1. **Ctrl + K** to open commit dialog
2. Type following pattern into "**Git / Author:**" dropdown field, replacing parts with personal data(**keep space and angle brackets characters**):

```
Name Surname <Email>
```

Comment: It's not saving it, do I have to do this everytime?

Comment: It actually saving it, you just need to type the first couple of letters of your name and then pick from the list. This way you can quickly select the name of anyone ever committed to the project as this list gets aggregated. I like this approach better than a git config because it allows multiple developers to work on one PC that is handy for pair programming for example.

Comment: In IntelliJ 2020.2, this only performs a commit by a representative author "on behalf of" the project configured author.  To reconfigure the official commit author see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45327500/2336934

Answer (score 11):

When you are in the commit dialog, just using Ctrl+Space to open the user list and choose one.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that you have installed git from git-scm.com.

For Linux or Mac OS use terminal.

For Windows environment:
Use git bash (comes together with git installation) or use Powershell.

Run:

```
git config --global user.name "Sam Smith"
git config --global user.email sam@example.com
```

Tricky part is: You have to commit at least one time from terminal.

```
git add my_awesome_file
git commit -m "My commit message"
```

VIOLA! Now your author is shown in IntelliJ commit panel.

(Note: If you work with different repositories using different emails don't use global configuration)

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would just copy and paste those two lines in your command prompt; that will set the appropriate values, including for the IDE.

If you really want to set it via the IDE for some reason, I would follow the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-vcs-specific-settings.html).

Answer (score 2):

Below is worked for me

root:~/git_workspace/dummyproject$ git config --global user.name "Krunal.Chauhan"
root:~/git_workspace/dummyproject$ git config --global user.email krunal@abcd.com

set username and email, then I have committed code and pushed it to git.
so changes have been reflected.
[image]

And verified on git
[image]