# How do I push to new Github account repo on IntelliJ?

Tags: git, github, git-config

I know this maybe a dump question but I seem to be unable to push my local commits up to a new accounts repo in github.

Recently, for a school project, I created a secondary account on Github `second_username` and forked a school project repo. I worked on it locally in IntelliJ and when I run `git push origin master`. It does not ask for my login credentials, which usually happens.
It returns `remote: Permission to second_username/ip.git denied to first_username` and `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/second_username/ip.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`.

I tried changing the git configurations of both local and global username and email to the `second_username` but it keeps saying that I am trying to push as `first_username`. I have run through all the settings in git on IntelliJ and it seems correct as my origin remote is set to the correct https url. I suspect it could be due to some login credentials that where unchanged as I always used the `first_username` while working on IntelliJ before today.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Git user in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275397/change-git-user-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: I checked the config files my user name and email are both set to the secondary acc username. However whenever i make a commit, amend or rebase anything locally, it keep showsing the author as the first username. It shows an error that my "Name <email>" for my amends does not exist or match any existing author. Yea I am on a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your account in:

> File-->Settings--->Version Control -->GitHub

Good luck!

Comment: I changed everything but the first account still persist

Answer (score 0):

Ah I managed to solve it. It was related to the windows credential manager saving my other account despite me setting the config file.