# How to change the Git Name in Intellij

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I have change my git name but still it doesn't reflect in my IntellIj I have changed to Gunveer Singh [image]
I have changed my name but still showing ExuberantGunveer

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275397/change-git-user-in-intellij-idea?

Comment: Yes I tried that too still getting an same Name . I have updated the name as mentioned.. even restarted the project

Comment: Do you see old name for old commits or for new ones as well?

Comment: This has been resolved .. Thank you ! Yeah earlier the issue was like I was trying for same branch .. Even if I commit still there is no change .. But when I deleted  the branch & started working on new one this issue get resolved

Answer (score 0):

When we make a change in config file of .git(which is hidden) . If the change doesn't reflect on intellij after restart . Then , we have to delete the branch & create a new one . For me it works like this .. Thank You !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).