# setting up git/github on a mac: error on reading usr/local/etc/gitconfig

Tags: macos, git, github

I set up git with

```
git config --global user.name myuser
git config --global user.email my@email.com
```

when I try to commit my new repo through github for mac I get this error:

fatal: unable to access '/usr/local/etc/gitconfig': Permission denied
 (128)

I have read the documentation on github and followed their instractions, but didn't get anywhere.

Could you help fix it?

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? Run `sudo ls -l  /usr/local/etc/gitconfig` to check.

Comment: It comes out I don't have the file, event if git config --list returns my parameters

Comment: Did you maybe install it using `homebrew`?

Comment: no, I don't know about homebrew. I used the git installer. I located the gitconfig file in /usr/local/git, tried to create /etc and copy the file there, chmod 755 it, and nothing changed, same error. thank you for helping

Comment: Try temporarily changing your name and see if that works and which file it updates `git config --global user.name freddyFrog`.

Comment: I can only imagine you configured your `user.name` and `user.email` when logged in as, or `su'ed to another account, or that you somehow have multiple, conflicting `git` installations. Try this command to find *ALL* gitconfig files `sudo find / -name ".gitconfig" -ls`

Comment: config --list returns changes, but I can't locate the file who's changed. I deleted /usr/local/git (I don't know how, may re-installing git), but the config file is still present and updated through git config --global

Comment: sudo find / -name ".gitconfig" -ls returns /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
21195287        8 -rw-r--r--    1 root             wheel                  26 Jun 20 09:19 /private/var/root/.gitconfig
21195299        8 -rw-r--r--    1 silvio           staff                  60 Jun 20 09:20 /Users/silvio/.gitconfig

Comment: So you have run `git config` both as root and as silvio.- was that your intention? EIther way, you have 2 git identities. I guess you also have two versions of the `git` binaries - one from Apple in `/usr/bin/git` and one from your own installation from the git installer in `/usr/local/bin` - can you run `ls` on both those locations and report back? I suspect the problem is that your PATH is not set to consistently choose one or the other git installations.

Comment: it seems I have not installed the apple git (???), but I just installed xcode on yosemite. any idea? `sh-3.2# cd /usr/local/bin`
 `sh-3.2# ls` 
`git-lfs  github  pandoc  pandoc-citeproc`
 `sh-3.2# cd /usr/bin/git` 
 `sh: cd: /usr/bin/git: Not a directory`

Answer (score 0):

`git config --global` is [supposed to write in `$HOME/gitconfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2114111/6309), your global config.

Double-check `$HOME` when you are typing this command, because if  `/usr/local/etc/gitconfig` is more of a system config file, more likely owned by root.

Comment: I don't have the file, tried do copy if from /usr/local/git, but the error is still there. how can I check $home? thx

Comment: Don't try to copy it, just make sure $HOME is correctly set. Also check your other environment variables: make sure you don't have some starting with GIT_. A `git config --global ` should create the `gitconfig` file at the right place, with the correct access rights.