# What should be the path of .gitconfig file in linux?

Tags: git, ubuntu, linux-kernel

Hello can anyone tell me where the .gitconfig file reside, i mean what is the folder where this file should be stored. I am seeing the linux kernel tutorials from KernelNewbies at stuck where that file should reside.
I am following this link http://kernelnewbies.org/FirstKernelPatch and under the heading setup git they tell me to make .gitconfig file now i dont know what should be the path.

Comment: To show the paths in use, configure git on-the-fly to display the file-names, e.g. `$ git -c core.editor=ls\ -al config --global --edit`.

Comment: Where in the home directory?

Comment: Here's a link to a related question with a fantastic answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-is-the-global-git-config-data-stored

Comment: And here's a link to the relevant doc page: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES

Answer (score 38):

Your global git configuration is written to `~/.gitconfig`.

To override git configuration on a per-project basis, write to `path/to/project/.git/config`.

However, you don't have to edit configuration files directly. You can set global or local configuration variables on the command line. For example, to set the global user name, use `git config --global user.name "your-username"`.

Answer (score 14):

There are three (or if you count `--file`, even *four*) places you can configure Git:

- At the machine level: `--system`.  Unless you are the system administrator, you do not want to use this one.
- At the user-specific level: `--global`.  This is the one you want here.
- At the repository level: `--local`, or without any `--whatever` flag at all.

The actual location of the user-specific file varies: the most common place is your home directory (`~` or `$HOME`) but there is this obnoxious `XDG_HOME` thing, and this other obnoxious thing called Windows :-) , that can mess with this.  So an easy way to avoid having to know where the file lives is to use `git config --global` to set things.

My recommendation is to use `git config --global core.editor name of your favorite editor` first, then to use `git config --edit` to make sure that this actually works.  For instance, if you prefer vim, run `git config --global core.editor vim`.  If you prefer nano, run `git config --global core.editor nano`.  If you like Emacs, or Notepad, or whatever, well, the pattern should be clear by now. :-)

Once you have set your `core.editor`, using `--edit` will make sure it really works, and you will be able to see the format for the settings file (it's basically an INI-style file).  Make sure that whatever editor you use, it writes text files as ASCII if possible, or UTF-8 when needing auxiliary non-ASCII characters, not "RichText" and not UTF-16, and without using a pointless byte-order mark ("BOM"), as these will give Git heartburn.

Besides `core.editor` (which you do not have to set, I just recommend it), you *must* set:

- `user.name "your name"`
- `user.email your-email@example.com`

and you probably *should* set:

- `core.pager "less -S"`
- `color.branch auto`
- `color.diff auto`
- `diff.renames true` (or even to `copy`)
- `diff.renameLimit 0`
- `merge.conflictstyle diff3`

although all of these are matters of taste.

Once you have your `core.editor` set, you can set these others with `git config --global var.iable "value"`, or with `git config --global --edit`.  The quotes here are needed only if the *`value`* is more than one word (contains whitespace) or needs other protection from the shell (has `$` or `*` characters in it, for instance).  (And: using `--edit` is particularly valuable when you have set something long and complicated, like an alias, and want to fix a small typo, or experiment, without having to re-enter the whole thing.)