# How to Upgrade GIT 32 bit to 64 bit on windows?

Tags: git

When I installed Git 2 years ago, I used the Git-1.9.5-preview20141217.exe to install it. I can't tell if that was a 32 or 64 bit installer.

I do know the path where it is installed is C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe and C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe.

I have read conflicting information that the 64 bit installers installed at that path also so it makes me even more confused. If this is a 32 bit installer,then I ask is there a way to upgrade it to 64 bit or am I stuck using the 32 bitversion?

There might not have been a 64 bit installer when I installed GIT orginally .

Comment: What? 64b things are installing themselves in a 32b directory? In 2014? What / where is that conflicting information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the latest Git for Windows releases are at [`github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

You will find installer and archives for 32 and 64 bits.

I personnaly simply uncompress [`PortableGit-prerelease-2.11.0.rc1.windows.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.0-rc1.windows.1/PortableGit-prerelease-2.11.0.rc1.windows.1-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere I want, and add that to my %PATH%.
You can have any number of Git versions that way.

Comment: Do mutiple versions installed side by side use the same database to see commit histories?

Comment: A git (any of your installed or uncompressed git) will only see the commit of the repo you are in, meaning the folder of the repo. Outside of that folder, a git has no knowledge of a database.

Comment: In other words, adding or removing or uninstalling some git has no effect on existing git repositories.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would recommend uninstalling the current version and doing a clean install of whatever new version you're trying for.

Comment: An explanation for the down vote would be appreciated.

Comment: Dumb question but when uninstalling git is history or anything lost?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is stored in your user profile folder and shouldn't be lost on uninstall, I haven't verified this though.

Comment: What about when installed on a server for the main repo's? Does it get installed under the user profile there of who ever installed it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to 

This will probably answer better than I can.