# to change git username

Tags: git, github

I have a problem with git. I have 2 users for different projects. Now when I am trying to push request, I get that

```
remote: Permission to secondUser/project2.git denied to firstUser.

The requested URL returned error: 403
```

As I understand I need to change username. 
After change username, I get the same error. Any idea

Comment: did you change the name using `--global` or not?

Comment: First search item on Google: https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: @MarceloFilho, yeah I have changed this property, but nothing

Comment: i see but you have the config file for your local repo and for the whole git in your computer, im asking what config did you change... if you have used `--global` you changed it for the whole git env in your computer, if not only for the local repo... check the `config` file in your user folder and `.gitconfig` file in the repo folder and let me know...

Comment: still up for this question?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I have changed using --global. I cannot find .gitconfig. Where is this file located?

Comment: Info related to gitconfig: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to

Answer (score 0):

This is a user rights issue.

If you have cloned your repository using SSH `git clone git@github.com:...` this is a SSH key issue. On GitHub users are authenticated by SSH keys, the SSH keys cannot be shared between two users. So switch your keys before to run `git push` in order to push as *secondUser*.

You could try to clone your repository using HTTPS `git clone https://github.com/...`. Then you will be able to push with the wanted user (It will ask you to enter your credentials).

Finally, you can also add the *firstUser* as a collaborators on the *secondUser/project2* (Settings > Collaborators).

Comment: You can check the andrejs-cainikovs comments for the switch things

Comment: yeah, it might be the case too... im not sure if he's talking about user NAME or user itself

Answer (score -2):

Listed Method 2 from jml:

Change Git remote url to https:

```
git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git


git push
```

To ensure that the commits appear as performed by USERNAME, one can setup the user.name and user.email for this project, too:

```
git config user.name USERNAME
git config user.email USERNAME@example.com
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the user name.