# Not able to change remote's URL to HTTPS from git

Tags: git, github, https, path, atlassian-sourcetree

Yesterday, I installed SourceTree on my desktop that uses Windows 10 as OS. After I cloned my first repository (and committing the files) I tried pushing them, but it didn't work. I have kinda figured out the problem, but there seems no way to fix it.

The error log said that I needed to change:

```
git://github.com/USERNAME/REP.git
```

To:

```
https://github.com/USERNAME/REP.git
```

After I changed the path from `git` to `https` it automatically changed back to `git`. I have tried looking up a fix, but I just found posts of people explaining how to change the path.

EDIT: Added an image to show what happends when I try changing it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue thanks to [ilooner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3811080/ilooner).

When I took a look at my config file using  `git config --list --show-origin` I saw that a weird configuration was set that changed https://github.com to git://github.com automatically. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGcZn.jpg

After that I manually went to my gitconfig file that was located in my C:/Users/USER and removed the part that I surrounded by red in the provided image.

After that I went ahead and changed the remote path to https://

Now it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your remote and then adding it again.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/justLars701/701.git
```

Comment: Is there anything hardcoded in your gitconfig? Instructions on how to find it are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to

Comment: I have found the issue: https://imgur.com/CmaGiIX. Thank you so much for your help!