# Launch Compare with previous from Visual Studio when in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

How can I revert these commands:

```
git config --global diff.tool vscode
git config --global difftool.vscode.cmd "code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE"
```

I think this is the reason why "Compare with previous" from Visual Studio is launched in vscode.

The commands I posted were intended to make vscode launch as the diff tool from cmd but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my settings

```
[diff]
    tool = vsdiffmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "vsdiffmerge"]
    cmd = \"E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\vsdiffmerge.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" //t
    keepBackup = false
```

Though, you should also be able to set these settings from VS directly.

Comment: Tanveer where you do you have these, in the .gitconfig of a project or is there a way to set these globally? Thank you

Comment: VS allows both global and repository configurations. I copied mine from a repository's config file in .git folder.

Comment: So each project has a .git folder accesible by \.git in Explorer, is there also a global repository where I can have basic git settings? (that I could override or extend as needed in each project). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, each repository has its own .git folder. I am not sure, though, where global settings are saved. A little googling should be able to answer that if you are interested.

Comment: There are some variants here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to I'll look into it. Thanks Tanveer!