# Why can’t I clone my remote repository onto my other machine?

Tags: git

I’m trying to copy my remote repository that I originally put up on github with my laptop, and now I want to work on it with my desktop. I’m new to git & github and don’t understand most of it. But the first thing I did was create the folder on my desktop. Went into that folder with git bash and then did git clone followed by the url. This is what I got.

```
Marian@Marian-PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/codeProjects/kaneConcrete
$ git clone https://github.com/spabsa/Kane-Concrete-Construction.git 2
Cloning into ‘Kane-Concrete-Construction’…
remote: Enumerating objects: 24, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (24/24), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (19/19), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD :wrong version number, errno 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

can someone give me a simplified explanation on what’s going on and how to fix it? Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the [latest Git version installed](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), and try again your git clone, this time from a regular CMD (not a Git bash), with the simplified path set as:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

(type `where git` first, to know where Git is installed, then set the PATH as indicated)

See if the issue (too old openssl version) persists.

Answer (score 0):

1. check your git version? update to newest.
2. check your network connection speed?
3. check your local proxy? change to http url for https_proxy.
4. check your ssl version, use TLS instead of SSL.

Comment: I did 1.  For 2. I was able to clone from my laptop on the same network, but my download speed is 8.25Mb/s and I have a ping of 41ms.  3. I don't know what that is hor how to do that, same with 4.

Comment: for 3, check your git config file, here to find out your git config file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to
for 4, check by:
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git ls-remote https://github.com/
or
see curl --version
to show your ssl(tls) version.

Comment: $ curl --version
curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1a (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.1.1 nghttp2/1.36.0
Release-Date: 2019-02-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy MultiSSL Metalink

Comment: and then I did git config, don't know what to do after that? I was told on sitepoint that proxy servers are for corporate environments and since I didn't know what one was I probably didn't have one. Though if it's likely an issue then what do I do after git config?

Comment: check your git config to see if there is HTTPS_PROXY or HTTP_PROXY config in the file.