# Git flow - error: Unablet to create a feature branch

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I'm trying to create a feature branch with the name "ft-setting-environment" and have already set up up the feature branch name prefixes as "ft-" during git flow initialization.

I'm using the command:

```
git flow feature start setting-enviroment
```

But I get this error:

> fatal: '?[D?[D?[D?[D?[D?[D?[Ct-?[C?[C?[C?[?[?[C?[C?[C]setting-environment' is not a valid branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.gitconfig` ([Where does git config --global get written to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-does-git-config-global-get-written-to))

Find `[gitflow "prefix"]` section

Fix the `feature` entry

```
feature = feature/
```

You could also use [`git flow config set`](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-git-flow-config#git-flow-config-set---update-the-git-flow-configuration).

---

If all fails, create the branch with `git checkout -b ft-setting-enviroment`

Comment: thanks, i later resort to git checkout -b ft-setting-enviroment