# Why is git searching outside of $HOME for .gitconfig on Windows?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I am using PowerShell on Windows 10.

```
PS Z:\> git config --global --edit
fatal: cannot create configuration file Z://.gitconfig: Permission denied
PS Z:\> echo $HOME
C:\Users\joseph64
PS Z:\> git --version
git version 2.36.1.windows.1
```

Everything I can find about config paths (e.g., [Where is the global git config data stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-is-the-global-git-config-data-stored), [First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)) is telling me that it should be looking for ~/.gitconfig. Where is it getting `Z:` from?

If I use `cmd` instead of PowerShell, I can see `HOMEDRIVE=Z:` and `HOMEPATH=\`, which at least makes the behavior of Git make sense. But that doesn't explain why Git behaves the same in PowerShell where only `HOME` is defined.

If I cannot convince Git to look for config files in my actual home directory, is there another way to configure global settings?

Comment: Do you have any environment variables beginning with `GIT_` in your environment?  If so, which ones?

Comment: @bk2204 I ran `Get-Variable` and there is nothing starting with `GIT`.

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour in `cmd` and in Git Bash?

Comment: In `cmd`, `HOME` does not exist, `​HOMEDRIVE=Z:` and `HOMEPATH=\​`. Git's behavior is the same which makes sense in that context. I suppose I could override it there but switching to cmd is not what I would call a solution.

Comment: Get-Variable returns PowerShell variables. Try `dir env:HOME*` and `dir env:USER*`. Unless your PowerShell $PROFILE script unsets HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH, they are defined in the powershell environment just like the cmd environment.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't realize there was a difference. I am rather confused as to what is setting `$HOME`, since if it's not an environment variable and does not point to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`... well, what use is it? But leaving that aside, I suppose that is the answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

Git for Windows looks in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% for your .gitconfig file or in a .config/ folder under that in case you have X Desktop style configuration folders. This means it is using the Windows specified domain profile folder and this is where your Z:\ has come from.

If there is nothing found then it uses %USERPROFILE%. These locations can be explicitly overridden by defining a HOME environment variable in which case that will be used.

Comment: `HOMEDRIVE`, `HOMEPATH`, and `USERPROFILE` are not set, so I don't see what those could have to do with anything. Moreover, as I showed in my question, `HOME` is set, and it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Just in case, open a `cmd` prompt and type `echo %HOMEDRIVE%`, `echo %HOMEPATH%` and `echo %USERPROFILE%`. Those variables might not be visible to Git Bash, but they might still influence where Git looks for your config files since `git.exe` is compiled as a Windows-native executable. And, strangely enough, on my PC `cmd` sees these, but not PowerShell, so I really mean in `cmd`.

Comment: I'm using PowerShell, not Git Bash. However, you may be on to something, since in cmd those do show up as `Z:`, `\​` and `C:\Users\joseph64` respectively. I have no idea what that might mean.