# After upgrade getting error "repository not owned by current user"

Tags: tortoisegit

After upgrading to latest tortoise git I get error below. When I commit from the command line, this works without error. I executed the global command but error persist.

[image: Error popup]

Comment: Please show the path here.

Comment: Does the path end with a slash? Add an exception without a slash at the end. - The last resort for now would be to add the '*' exception which disables this security check - only do this if you trust all users on your machine.

Comment: Path is 'c:/Programming/Projects/DemoProject_V2/'
And you meant to add simple '*' as safe directory ? Still get the same error, printout is :

git config --global --get-all safe.directory

Prints out:'\*'

Comment: @MrTux Can you help ? As I mentioned this works wit git command line and only happened after the latest tortoise git upgrade

Comment: git config --global --get-all safe.directory should print out * without quotes

Comment: That worked , thanks so much ! The quotes and non quotes is the worst confusing thing with git. Some commands need the quotes some not, there should be a consistent way to do this !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

MrTux gave the correct answer and but in a comment, I just want to make sure that this is marked as answered.

In .gitconfig (I added it in global) this works:

```
[user]
    name = <your name>
    email = <your email>
[safe]
    directory = *
```

Comment: I added an answer based on my comment

Comment: I wasn't sure where I would find my global .gitignore on a Windows machine. I found it in C:\Users\[myusername]\.gitignore

Comment: `directory = *` that is what helped, ty!

Comment: What does this do, though?

Answer (score 9):

Also something that worked for me related to above comments.

```
git config --global --add safe.directory *
```

Answer (score 8):

The origin for this "error" is a safety check that was [added in Git](https://github.blog/2022-04-12-git-security-vulnerability-announced/) to address CVE 2022-24765.

Therefore, one needs to put working trees that are on a path not owned by the current user on a safe.directory list.

There seems, however, be an inconsistency between vanilla Git and libgit2 regarding the handling of trailing slashes. For libgit2 to recognize a path correctly as safe, it must not end with a slash.

As a last resort, one can also add the `*` exception which completely disables this security check - only do this if you trust all users on your machine. `.gitconfig` (normally located in `%HOME%` or `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, i.e., your user profile folder, cf. [Where is the global git config data stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2114111/3906760)) should look like this:

```
[safe]
    directory = *
```

Comment: normally path to .gitconfig file will be C:\Users\MyLogin\.gitconfig . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-is-the-global-git-config-data-stored

Answer (score 0):

git config --global --add safe.directory '*'

This worked for me to be able to commit and get to the push confirmation window.  However it is now asking for my username and password.  I enter my credentials and it works just fine, but I've never had to do this in the past.  How to I make it stop asking here?