# Why is git looking for its config on a mapped network drive?

Tags: windows, git, command-line

My Git command line program in Windows 10 keeps loading its config from the `H:` drive.

The `.gitconfig` there (to which I do not have permissions to modify) does not allow me to store credentials so I get prompted for a password.

Disconnecting the network drive fixes the problem. I guess git looks somewhere else for its config when that drive is disconnected. I have tried to prevent the drive from auto-mapping by issuing the command `net use /persistent:no` but it keeps coming back. This is in a corporate environment with group policies and I do not have admin rights on my machine.

How to I tell git to never look at that mapped drive again for its config?

Comment: How did you install git? [Double check where git thinks the config is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114111/where-is-the-global-git-config-data-stored)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to a reference given in another config file, probably at global level. Try:

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

… to get all your parameters displayed, followed by the sources they were picked from.

Answer (score 0):

Git reads the home directory from the environment variable `HOME`.  This is usually set to `USERPROFILE` if you haven't set it yourself, and this may be set to a directory you don't want.

You can simply set `HOME` to the location of what you want as your home directory, and that will work.  To persist it, you can save the value in `.bashrc` in your default home directory (the weird H drive), with something like this:

```
export HOME=/c/Users/bk2204/
```

This syntax also works for setting the environment variable in the shell manually; the `export` is required so that child processes of the shell (including Git) will inherit the value.

Note that you need to use the Unix-style paths specified in Git Bash, and not a Windows-style path.  This also only affects Git Bash and not other environments.

If you want to set the environment variable permanently for all environments, [this documentation tells you how to do that](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html).  It should be sufficient to specify `HOME`, but in that case, you *should* use a Windows-style path.

You could also use Windows Subsystem for Linux, which will store your data in a separate location.